# PhpDesigner 7, Box Shadow

Tags: css

I am trying to use box shadow properties on PhpDesigner 7 and as soon as I enter the code, syntax such as box-shadow, it is giving me syntax error. Non of the box shadow codes is working in PhpDesigner 7.

I was wondering that does anyone have a solution for it and experienced this issue? 
I don't want to switch to another IDE just for box shadow but I still need to use it for my website. Please advise me.

Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score 2):

It's because phpDesigner currently don't support CSS3. Both CSS3 and HTML5 will soon be supported in phpDesigner.